# link an image in tt_news

Tags: image, hyperlink, typo3, tt-news

I'm using TYPO3 4.2.8 and tt_news 2.5.2. I tried the following [snippet](http://typo3.org/documentation/snippets/sd/240/):

```
plugin.tt_news.displaySingle {
    image {
        # turn off default popup anchor
        imageLinkWrap = 0
        # add our link to the first URL in links field
        stdWrap.typolink {
            parameter = {current:1}
            parameter {
            setCurrent.field = links
            setCurrent.listNum = 0
                insertData = 1
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added an image to my news and also put a link into the link field (in the tab relations).

```
<LINK http://www.yourwesite.com/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/broschure.pdf _blank>Download brochure</LINK>
```

But if I look at the news I don't have a link on the image. What do I have to change to get it work with my old version of tt_news?

**Edit:**

Now I tried it with gernericmarkers (idea from [this topic](http://www.typo3forum.net/forum/news-tt_news-mininews-co/51541-tt_news-bilder-verlinken.html)). My TS looks like the following:

```
temp.img = COA
temp.img.5 = IMAGE
temp.img.5 < plugin.tt_news.displaySingle.image
temp.img.5 {
    required = 1
    wrap = |
    file {
        import = uploads/pics/
        import.field = image
        import.listNum = 0
    }
    titleText.field = title
    altText.field = title
    if.isTrue.field = links
    imageLinkWrap.typolink.parameter.data = field:links
}

plugin.tt_news.genericmarkers.imagewithlink < temp.img
```

The marker is working but there is no content displayed in the news. What is wrong with my TS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works in your old tt_news version but at least from version 3.0+ you can simply use the marker `<!--###LINK_ITEM###--> around your image <!--###LINK_ITEM###-->` inside your template to link anything you like to the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet works, but you have to insert the link without the  tags into the link field.
e.g.

```
http://www.yourwesite.com/fileadmin/user_upload/downloads/broschure.pdf _blank
```